# Whats the logic of the integral?

Tags: integration

$$ dq = λ\,ds = λr\,dΘ $$
This kind of expressions are confusing to me. I think I should have learnt integral logic better. Would you suggest me a video or source that teaches integral logic. I want to understand this kind of expressions easily.

Comment: The first one is a statement about charge or mass densities (not strictly speaking about math). The second one is about polar coordinates, which you can learn about in any chapter on double integrals in a calculus textbook.

Answer (score -1):

According to this site, they are equations about elasticity one must know.
[http://home.ku.edu.tr/~generalphysics/phys102/2012/Quizzes/Ch21Quiz1_Solutions.pdf](http://home.ku.edu.tr/%7Egeneralphysics/phys102/2012/Quizzes/Ch21Quiz1_Solutions.pdf)